# Angular: How do you focus an input inside a ngbDropdown Menu?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to use an ElementRef to focus on an input. This works fine except for inside a dropdown from the ng-bootstrap library. How do you trigger the event in a [ngbDropdown](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/examples)?

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z7q9xm

**component class**

```js
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-dropdown-basic',
  templateUrl: './dropdown-basic.html'
})
export class NgbdDropdownBasic {
  @ViewChild("search") searchField: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild("searchOutside") searchFieldOutside: ElementRef;

  onToggle(dropDownOpen: boolean) {
    if (dropDownOpen) {
      this.searchField.nativeElement.focus();
    }
  }

  focusOtherField() {
    this.searchFieldOutside.nativeElement.focus();
  }
}
```

**component template**

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col"><h3>Example 1: Inside dropdown <br>(not working)</h3></div>
</div>
<div class="row form-group">
  <div class="col">
    <div ngbDropdown (openChange)="onToggle($event)" class="d-inline-block">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle dropdown</button>
      <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
        <div class="p-2"><input #search name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..."></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col"><h3>Example 2: Outside dropdown</h3></div>
</div>
<div class="row form-group">
  <div class="col-auto"><button (click)="focusOtherField()" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Focus this field:</button></div>
    <div class="col">
    <input #searchOutside name="searchOutside" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: change the z-order to around 10.  You can't focus on an element that is not on top.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that at the point of clicking on the dropdown and calling your `onToggle`, the DOM has not yet been updated to render the dropdown and the input within the dropdown.

What you can do is inject a `ChangeDetectorRef` into the component via the constructor:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
...

export class NgbdDropdownBasic {
  ...
  constructor(private _cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
```

and call `this._cdRef.detectChanges();` before you focus on the input in your `onToggle` method:

```
onToggle(dropDownOpen: boolean) {
  if (dropDownOpen) {
    this._cdRef.detectChanges();
    this.searchField.nativeElement.focus();
  }
}
```

This will result in the dropdown and input being rendered, so that when you call `this.searchField.nativeElement.focus();` it is already visible and will get the focus.

Please see [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z7q9xm-x7nvlh?file=app/dropdown-basic.ts) for a working demo.